# How to check if user is in correct directory using Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to check if the user is in the correct directory in the command prompt using a Windows batch file. The correct directory is stored in a system environment variable. For example, if `HOME` is set to `C:\path\to\home`, I want to know if the user is in that directory:

```
c:\some\directory>check.bat
No

c:\path\to\home>check.bat
Yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if /i "%CD%"=="%HOME%" (
    echo Yes
) else (
    echo No
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if /i "%CD%"=="%HOME%" echo woooooooooo!
```

%CD% represents the current directory for the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the location the script in being run from with a check like this

```
if /i "%~dp0"=="%HOME%\"
```

Or check the current working directory with `%CD%`

However, you could also just make it the correct directory

```
cd /d "%HOME%"
```

---

For a true directory comparison where folders may or may not have a trailing backslash

```
for %%A in ("%~dp0%\") do for %%B in ("%HOME%\") do if /i "%%~fA"=="%%~fB"
```

Comment: David, your first solution will fail because `%home%` is missing a trailing slash.  The second solution should also include the `/d` switch in the cd command.

Comment: @foxidrive  Yeah, I thought about both of those items, but just did not feel like spending the extra time adding them at the time of writing this quick anser. The `/d` is only needed if changing drives.